# Stop Localization in Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

If I Want a Pod for example [CountryPicker](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CountryPickerView), It uses Localization. 
I Want to stop localization and want it to be English in all of the app languages.
How to stop its localization.

Answer (score 2):

BTW the localization follows your app settings , also remove any other language from your pod configuration here

[image]

Comment: I found the only Development language, but it also do localization